# Using Grep & Regex to strip URL strings from .txt

Tags: python, regex, grep, sanitization

I am having problems figuring out the best way to strip URLs from a .txt file.  I realize that regex is probably the best way to go about it but it's been a while since I did anything in Python.  Not a homework question, just a personal project.

Here is a sample of the file:

> 738 \loch\af4\dbch\af31505\hich\f4 \u8232\'5f}{\field{*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 \hich\af4\dbch\af31505\loch\f4 HYPERLINK "https://archive.org/randomURL1?fref=grp_mmbr_list"}{
>   \rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 {*\datafield 
>   00d0c9ea79f9bace118c8200aa004ba90b0200000003000000e0c9ea79f9bace118c8200aa004ba90b31505\hich\f4 \u8232\'5f}{\field{*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 \hich\af4\dbch\af31505\loch\f4 HYPERLINK "https://archive.org/randomURL2?fref=grp_mmbr_list"}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 
>   \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 {*

As you can see, it's a mess.  At least it seems that there is always a 'HYPERLINK "' before each URL and a 'fref' after so I could use the regex start of line and end of line operators.

I was thinking this:

```
grep ^HYPERLINK $fref testsample.txt | echo output.txt
```

But it's not working for me.  The desired output would look like this in a new file:

```
link1
link2
linkn...
```

Update: I found out how to pull URLs and put them in a new file with this command:

```
grep 'https://www\.[[:alpha:]]\+\.[[:alpha:]]\+' testsample.txt > testfile2.txt
```

But my output looks like this:

> \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 \loch\af4\dbch\af31505\hich\f4 \u8232\'5f}{\field{*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 \hich\af4\dbch\af31505\loch\f4 HYPERLINK "httjps://archive.org/randomURL1?fref=grp_mmbr_list"}{
>   \loch\af4\dbch\af31505\hich\f4 \u8232\'5f}{\field{*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 \hich\af4\dbch\af31505\loch\f4 HYPERLINK "httjps://archive.org/randomURL1?fref=grp_mmbr_list"}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 
>   \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 \loch\af4\dbch\af31505\hich\f4 \u8232\'5f}{\field{*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 \hich\af4\dbch\af31505\loch\f4 HYPERLINK "httjps://archive.org/randomURL2?fref=grp_mmbr_list"}{

It seems like it's pulling the whole line and not just the URL.  Any help with confuguring the 'end of line' parameter would be very much appreciated.

**Solved**

```
grep -Eo '\"https?:\/\/[^"]+\"' testsample.txt > testfile2.txt
```

Comment: Will you post your 'solved' statement here as an answer so it can be found easily by those in need. Your question is a *long* read! I might  have to call in for food before I finish reading it. Fortunately, I have nothing better to do because the vital info is at the very end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract all links into a new file with `grep` command:

```
grep -Po '\"\Khttps?:\/\/[^"]+(?=\")' testsample.txt > testfile2.txt
```

Now, `testfile2.txt` file should contain the following:

```
https://archive.org/randomURL1?fref=grp_mmbr_list
https://archive.org/randomURL2?fref=grp_mmbr_list
```

**Note**: if `-P` option isn't supported on your side, use `-E` to allow extended regexp expressions:

```
grep -Eo '\"https?:\/\/[^"]+\"' testsample.txt > testfile2.txt
```

---

To remove all links from the initial file (in place) use `sed` command
 with `-ri` options:

```
sed -ri 's/\"https?:\/\/[^"]+\"//g' /tmp/testsample.txt
```

---

Alternative solution using `re.sub()` function(used a test string instead of file):

```
import re

s = '''
738 \loch\af4\dbch\af31505\hich\f4 \u8232\'5f}{\field{*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 \hich\af4\dbch\af31505\loch\f4 HYPERLINK "https://archive.org/randomURL1?fref=grp_mmbr_list"}{ \rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 {*\datafield 00d0c9ea79f9bace118c8200aa004ba90b0200000003000000e0c9ea79f9bace118c8200aa004ba90b31505\hich\f4 \u8232\'5f}{\field{*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 \hich\af4\dbch\af31505\loch\f4 HYPERLINK "https://archive.org/randomURL2?fref=grp_mmbr_list"}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af4 \ltrch\fcs0 \f4\cf1\insrsid10228738 {*
'''

result = re.sub(r'\"https?:\/\/[^"]+\"', '', s)
print(repr(result))
```

The output:

```
"\n738 \\loch\x07f4\\dbch\x07f31505\\hich\x0c4 舲'5f}{\x0cield{*\x0cldinst {\rtlch\x0ccs1 \x07f4 \\ltrch\x0ccs0 \x0c4\\cf1\\insrsid10228738 \\hich\x07f4\\dbch\x07f31505\\loch\x0c4 HYPERLINK }{ \rtlch\x0ccs1 \x07f4 \\ltrch\x0ccs0 \x0c4\\cf1\\insrsid10228738 {*\\datafield 00d0c9ea79f9bace118c8200aa004ba90b0200000003000000e0c9ea79f9bace118c8200aa004ba90b31505\\hich\x0c4 舲'5f}{\x0cield{*\x0cldinst {\rtlch\x0ccs1 \x07f4 \\ltrch\x0ccs0 \x0c4\\cf1\\insrsid10228738 \\hich\x07f4\\dbch\x07f31505\\loch\x0c4 HYPERLINK }{\rtlch\x0ccs1 \x07f4 \\ltrch\x0ccs0 \x0c4\\cf1\\insrsid10228738 {*\n"
```

Comment: I don't understand your output

Comment: @daviddavidson, *to strip URLs from a .txt file* - those were your words. The output has no links after replacement as expected

Comment: This grep command didn't work.  I looked in the grep command list and I didn't see -P.  Excuse my ignorance, I know you're trying to help

Comment: @daviddavidson, that's not true. It works fine. I've tested on your input. Also try with `grep -E `

Comment: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

I believe it works on your end but for whatever reason it's not working here.  There's the grep output after I input your command, and the file is blank.  It seems I don't have a -P command.

Comment: That worked, it was the -Eo , thank you very much!!

Thanks to everyone else as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the link is always wrapped in the double quotes:

```
https?:\/\/[^"]+
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO36zG/1)

Details:

- `https?:\/\/` - match `http://` or `https://`
- `[^"]+` - match following one or more non-`"` characters

Comment: I see that the regex accurately pulls out the links, but how would it fit into a grep?

I get this: grep https?:\/\/[^"]+ testsample2.txt > testfile2.txt

But the terminal is just hung and is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using your assumptions, and that the URLs are always preceded by double quotes:

```
>>> content = open('testsample.txt').read()
>>> import re
>>> oneLink = re.compile(r'HYPERLINK\s+"(.*?)\?fref=')
>>> for link in oneLink.findall(content):
...     link
...     
'https://archive.org/randomURL1'
'https://archive.org/randomURL2'
```

Comment: For the 'content' line, is it possible to pull in testsample.txt instead of copy+pasting?

Comment: There it is. --

Comment: Thank you but we figured it out with a grep command.  I'll keep note of that though, thank you!